# On Click event the textarea field should be empty

Tags: angular10

I am a very new user of Angualr and currently using Angular 10. I want the **textarea field** that should be empty after click on the **clear** button. But this code is not working that I want to do. Could someboday help me.
Thanks.

**HTM file**

```
<button (click)="ClearField()" type="button">clear field</button> 
<textarea class="form-control  rows=10 cols=50 cstm-textarea" #box (keyup)="OnUpdateTextArea(box.value)">
</textarea>
```

**.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  str = '';

  OnUpdateTextArea(value: string) {
    this.str = value;
    console.log("text area value:", this.str);
    
  }

  ClearField() {
    this.str = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe binding can fix this problem.

```
<button (click)="ClearField()" type="button">clear field</button> 
<textarea [(ngModel)]="str" class="form-control  rows=10 cols=50 cstm-textarea">
</textarea>
```

and ts I believe can stay the same.

You should look into [one way and two way binding](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it isn't working. Could you please state how i have to handle 'str' in ts file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem:

```
<button (click)="ClearField(box)" type="button">clear field</button> 
<textarea class="form-control  rows=10 cols=50 cstm-textarea"  #box (keyup)="OnUpdateTextArea(box.value)">
</textarea>
```